# Typescript AMD Target Resolving to CommonJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I have a tsconfig in my project that specifies a module target of 'amd' but when my file compiles I am getting an output that looks more like CommonJS. Example:

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise", "dom"]
    }
}
```

Typescript File:

```
export function test() {
    console.log('Starting Up', '<--------------');
}
```

Compiled File:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function test() {
        console.log('Starting Up', '<--------------');
    }
    exports.test = test;
});
```

Expected Compiled File:

```
define([], function () {
    function test() {
        console.log('Starting Up', '<--------------');
    }
    return { test: test };
});
```

It's the 'export' object that's throwing me off. This should not be necessary for an AMD module, only a return statement. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Of course mine gets marked as a duplicate even though I asked it first ;). Anyways the solution in the other question does work for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. That is the shape of TypeScript's AMD output and it is AMD compliant. AMD offers this facility and TypeScript uses it.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. The environment that my code runs in seems to be overwriting the exports object, so I'm having to go into my compiled files and change the export.function line to a return statement every time I push my code.

Comment: @JonLamb what environment is that? Some loaders might do that if they detect or assume CommonJS

Comment: It's with an ERP system called NetSuite. They use a java interpreter called Rhino to interpret the AMD modules. Usually, the exports object is available but it seems like in some instances, depending on the scope of your custom module, they have disabled or are ignoring the exports object. I think my only option, in this case, is to use gulp or something to switch out the syntax.

Comment: @JonLamb maybe file a feature request on the TypeScript repository to allow configuring the emit.